# Find the smallest positive integer greater than $100$ whose digits in bases $4,5,$ and $6$ form a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

Here is a math question that I made up, but I don't know how easily it is solved:

Find the smallest positive integer greater than $100$ (or prove that no such number exists)  whose digits when read left to right in bases $4,5,$ and $6$ form a perfect square.

*Clarification*: Since there seem to be many interpretations of what my question was, here is clarification: My original question's intention was to find a base $10$ number that when converted to bases $4,5,$ and $6$ had the digits read from left to right in each of them be a perfect square.

For example, take the number $200_{10} = 3020_{4} = 1300_5 = 532_6$. This doesn't work since not all of $3020,1300,$ and $532$ are perfect squares.

Comment: I assume you rather mean: You look for a digit *digit sequence* of at least three digits $\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ such that the *interpretation* of this digit sequence as a base 4 number is a square, the interpretation as a base 5 number is a square, and the interpretation as a base 6 number is a square? (For the fact that an *integer* is a square would not depend on the base used for its representation; even a roman number such as CXLIV is a square ...)

Comment: $121$ is such a number, if I have understood the question correctly.

Comment: Or this: If the solution were $N=42=42_{10}=222_4=132_5=110_6$ then the integers (all in base $10$!) $222$, $132$, $110$ shall be squares?

Comment: Yes, $25_6$ would be considered a square.

Comment: I guess there is still a clarification needed: "the digits read from left to right in each of them *interpreted in base $10$* be a perfect square."

Comment: Does there exist such a number in this case?

Comment: Something weird is going on. For bases $4$ and $5$ only, first numbers are $1=1_4=1_5$, $25=121_4=100_5$, $65536=100000000_4=4044121_5$, $76176=102212100_4=4414201_5$. Now bizarre part: $5_{10}=11_4=10_5$, $256_{10}=10000_4=2011_5$, $276_{10}=10110_4=2101_5$. I have no explanation right now.

Comment: Hmm. So it appears like you are getting perfect squares in the digits for bases $4$ and $5$ for your first example then getting perfect squares in bases $10$ and $4$ for your other example. What is the bizarre part?

Comment: @user19405892 Take $76176$. We have $76176_{10}=102212100_4=4414201_5$ and $102212100_{10}=10110_{10}^2, 4414201_{10}=2101_{10}^2$. That was our requirement and that's how I found the number. I see no good reason for it to have other properties, but: $76176_{10}=276_{10}^2$ (number itself is a square) and, surprisingly, $276_{10}=10110_4=2101_5$. I see no reason to be so, but it *almost* holds for all numbers (for two bases).

Comment: My original question did not require the base $10$ digits to form a perfect square. Did you just realize that it was a perfect square in base $10$ by coincidence?

Comment: @user19405892 I didn't require a number itself to be a square during my search. The fact that nevertheless all found numbers are doesn't seem like a coincidence. As I said, something weird is going on.

Comment: Yes, there must be some deeper result that can be proven here. Also have you tried it as well for base $6$ or $3$ bases in general and seen if the result holds?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32758/discussion-between-user19405892-and-abstraction).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, if I read the question properly, is $121$.  $121_4=25_{10}, 121_5=36_{10}, 121_6=49_{10}$  This reflects $121_b=b^2+2b+1=(b+1)^2$  The same thing works for any polynomial square as long as the base is high enough to avoid overflow, so $144$ is a square in any base that allows $4$, $961$ is a square in any base that allows $9$, and so on.

Comment: What if I changed the question to greater than $1000$? What would it be then?

Comment: @user19405892 After your clarification this isn't an answer to **your** question. And for your question, after $1$ there seems to be no such number at least up to $1000000000$ (or my PC tells me so).

Comment: Yes. So I guess this is an open problem now then? Does there exist such a number?

Comment: You can just add zeros to make it as large as you want.  $1000002000001=1000001^2$ in any base $3$ or larger, for example  This reflects that $(b^6+1)^2=b^{12}+2b^6+1$

Comment: My original question's intention was to find a base 10 number that when converted to base $4,5,$ and $6$ had the digits read from left to right in each of them be a perfect square.